# Match values inside of a block with delimiters PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

everyone i have a Regex question here, i want to parse this Log file, right now i want to get the keys and values inside of `SESSION`

The problem is that the logs don't all look the same, some of them lack the # characters enclosing the 'SESSION', they all contain the word SESSION to start off the block of variables however, and they all end with another block which always contains either the words "POST" or "API CURL CALL".

So i have to use quantifiers most likely to make it disregard anything in between those strings but when match any sets of keys and values (separated by :) inside of these two other values...

That's a mouthful just talking about it... i'm completely stumped, so i turn to you guys for some guidance and help in this matter.
The goal is to parse these shitty logs into something i can actually read quickly and understand.

I'm creating a class in PHP to do that and spit out some nice HTML formatted logs.
This is the log file as it stands.

```
[05:40:40] ################
[05:40:40] #### SOURCE ####: /zalo/vn/interface.call.php
[05:40:40] #### REQUEST ####: /zalo/vn/interface.call.php
[05:40:40] #### Refer: http://app.com/zalo/vn/?v=1&adsid=d6e5f33e5a94d9fafaf15dc0cf4a1e5&sub_id=170100sf01435487523&sub_id1=232s5
[05:40:40] #### SESSION #####
[05:40:40] v: 1 
[05:40:40] adsid: d6e5f33e5a94d93sfsf5dc0cf4a1e5 
[05:40:40] sub_id: 799e12b08fa1edes1d7bgsg0506a6e9 
[05:40:40] landingpage: http%3A%2F%2Fapp.com%2Fzalo%2Fvn%2Finterface.call.php 
[05:40:40] c_id: da21bae82c02d1e2b8168d57cd3fbab7 
[05:40:40] nId: 3943 
[05:40:40] partner: Marvel
[05:40:40] country_code: 84 
[05:40:40] country: VN 
[05:40:40] url: http://app.com/zalo/vn/ 
[05:40:40] campaign_id: 1066 
[05:40:40] source: web 
[05:40:40] msisdn: 906346534 
[05:40:40] Phone: 906346534 
[05:40:40] #### POST ####
[05:40:40] action: subscribe 
[05:40:40] Phone: 906346534 
[05:40:40] ################
[05:40:40] #### API CURL CALL ####
```

Ideally what i'd want to keep is this section

```
v: 1 
adsid: d6e5f33e5a94d93sfsf5dc0cf4a1e5 
sub_id: 799e12b08fa1edes1d7bgsg0506a6e9 
landingpage: http%3A%2F%2Fapp.com%2Fzalo%2Fvn%2Finterface.call.php 
c_id: da21bae82c02d1e2b8168d57cd3fbab7 
nId: 3943 
partner: Marvel
country_code: 84 
country: VN 
url: http://app.com/zalo/vn/ 
campaign_id: 1066 
source: web 
msisdn: 906346534 
Phone: 906346534
```

I probably need a lookbehind-lookahead combination of some sort.

```
(?=SESSION).*?(?<=POST)
```

Something along these lines but that also removes the timestamps the actual SESSION and POST keywords that i don't require.

Comment: @michaJlS i've tried a few different things i've seen online

`/(?<=#### SESSION #####).*?(?=\[05:40:40\] #### POST ####)/si`

Lookbehinds like that look like they might work, but i cant use #* for instance, i must provide a very specific string to start off, which is a problem because even though i know the string will contain SESSION, i don't know exactly if it starts with #, just the word SESSION or -- SESSION for instance...

Comment: @michaJlS i've also included a perhaps better example in the question.

Comment: So, you already know how to match these blocks, right? Why not just remove all the details and lines you do not need?

Comment: You can try something [like this demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/742060) for regex explanation see regex101 [part 1 to match SESSION part](https://regex101.com/r/GgfZo5/1), and [part 2 to extract key/values](https://www.regex101.com/r/zZMhdZ/1).

Comment: @bobblebubble I'm not sure why you provided a working answer as a comment.

Comment: @JonnySerra, if bobblebubble's solution works perfectly for you, ask for it to be posted as an answer so you can accept it.  If it doesn't solve all your cases, please provide additional sample(s) with different formats.

Comment: @mickmackusa I was too tired already to write long explanation of the regex and was also not sure if it's satisfying solution (can post if wanted another time).

Answer (score 1):

If the file's not too big you could just loop through the whole thing:

```
$foo = file("test.txt");
$insession = false;
foreach ($foo as $line) {
    if (!$insession) {
        if (strpos($line, "SESSION") === false) continue;
        $insession = true;
        continue;
    }
    if (strpos($line, "POST") !== false) break;
    if (preg_match("/^\[[\d:]+?\] (.*)$/", $line, $matches)) {
        echo "$matches[1]\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading logs line by line would be more memory efficient

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming this is a) a fairly small file, and b) happening in real time during an HTTP request. If either of those is not true, there are better approaches to this.